# Unable to access array content of first JavaScript file in second javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have used arrays 'ParticularsArr' and 'AmountArr' to fill data in the table in my first js file (script.js).

```
var row = 1;
var ParticularsArr = new Array;
var AmountArr = new Array;
var ParticularsAmountArrIndex = 0;
var ParticularsDel;

$(document).ready(function() { 
    makeNull();
    //-----------------------code for initializing add button------------------------------------------
    $("#add").click(function() {
        rowAdder();
        makeNull();
    });

    //-------------------------Code for adding row--------------------------------------------
    function rowAdder() {
        ParticularsArr[ParticularsAmountArrIndex] = document.getElementById("particulars").value;
        AmountArr[ParticularsAmountArrIndex] = document.getElementById("amount").value;

        if (!ParticularsArr || !AmountArr) {
            alert("Please enter the values inside all the field.");
            return;
        }

        var display = document.getElementById("table-1");
        var newRow = display.insertRow(row);    
        var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

        var StringEntity = "<button id='remove'>X</button>";

        cel1.innerHTML = ParticularsArr[ParticularsAmountArrIndex];
        cel2.innerHTML = AmountArr[ParticularsAmountArrIndex];
        cel3.innerHTML = StringEntity;             //"<button id='remove'>X</button>";
    
        row++;
        
        ParticularsAmountArrIndex++;
    }

    //------------------Code to put null values in the input -----------------------------
    function makeNull() {
        document.getElementById("particulars").value = "";
        document.getElementById("amount").value = "";
    }

    //--------------------------Code for 'X'(delete) button-------------------------------
    $(document).on('click', '#remove', function() { 
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        row--;
    });

    $("#preview").click(function() { 
        window.open("preview.html","_blank");

    });
});
```

This is a second JavaScript file (script-preview.js), I want to retrieve the array and show the table of content which I stored in the array, on another HTML page, but I am not able to get contents inside the array, it shows undefined.

```
var row_2 = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

    for(var i=0; i<=ParticularsArr.length; i++) {
        var dis## Heading ##play = document.getElementById("table_1");
        var newRow = display.insertRow(row_2);    
        var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

        cel1.innerHTML = ParticularsArr[i];
        cel2.innerHTML = AmountArr[i];
    
        row_2++;
    }

});
```

First HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Commpatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profit and Loss Statement</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
        integrity=""sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2" 
        crossorigin="anonymous""></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">

</head>
<body>    
    <div id="adder">
        <p id="heading-1">Profit Statement</p>
        <table id="adderhd">
            <tr>
                <th>PARTICULARS</th>
                <th>AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="text" id="particulars" value=""></th>
                <th><input type="number" id="amount" value=""><button id="add">Add</button></th>
                <div id="previewbtn"><button id="preview">Preview Data</button></div>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>

    <div id="tables">
        <div>
            <table id="table-1">
                <tr>
                    <th>PARTICULARS</th>
                    <th>AMOUNT</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <!-- JQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
    <script src="js/jQuery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Commpatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profit and Loss Statement preview</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-Preview.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
        integrity=""sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2" 
        crossorigin="anonymous""></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">

</head>
<body>    
    <div id="profit-border">    
        <div id="adder">
            <p id="heading_1">Profit Statement</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="table-outline">
            <div>
                <table id="table_1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>PARTICULARS</th>
                        <th>AMOUNT</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
    <script src="js/jQuery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script-preview.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every HTML page has its own JavaScript variables, they don't transfer.

Comment: If you want to transfer data between pages, use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: There are 2 problems that I see, 1st: the 2nd function might execute before the target array is actually populated, 2nd: they must both be executed on a single web page, because JS is not persisted when you traverse the website. If you need persistence on the client side, you could use 'localStorage'.

Comment: ** @Teemu and Barmer ** 
I have two HTML file where the first JavaScript code mentioned above is associated with first HTML file and the second code associated with second, on first page there is a table where entries are added and stored in array I want to access those contents of array on my second JavaScript file.
So I have written code in second file to retrieve the data from array which is located in first JavaScript file but I am not able to get contents of array it is giving me error as undefined array.

Comment: If you want that the array is persisted even after closing the browser, use localStorage, otherwise use sessionStorage.

Comment: Files don't do anything alone when they're lying on your server. Are you loading these files to a HTML document in a browser, if you are, how are they related to each other. Typically you can load only a single HTML file in a single document, what are you doing to get two HTML files running on your browser at the same time? Do you have `iframe` elements? Do you have a pop-up window? Have you loaded the HTML files to separate tabs, or have you loaded them into separate browser instances or even into two different browsers ..?

Comment: @Teemu I have added both the HTML files to get more clarity.

Comment: Please read my comment above, and answer the question, there's a lot of alternatives, if not any of these, please explain, how the files are related to each other, when they are loaded into a browser.

Comment: @Teemu there is a button preview, after clicking on that button another HTML page will open. I have written a Jquery for it at the end. So I want to use data stored on first page to second page with an array.

Comment: OK, now that is clear. Please add that information to your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the array is persisted on the client (browser) even after closing the browser, use `localStorage`, otherwise use `sessionStorage`.

Both storages requires the set values to be string, so you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

**page 1: (save)**

sessionStorage.setItem('myParticularsArr', JSON.stringify(ParticularsArr));

**page 2: (retrieve)**

var ParticularsArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myParticularsArr'));

Comment: This is working but only for string entity, amount column is still getting empty, what should I use for integers?

Comment: do you know anything which will work in same manner for integers.

Comment: @Siddhesh This will work for almost every data type except functions.

Comment: Yes, it is working for Integer too.
Thanks for the help **@boy and @Temmu**